# I import the libraries and I defined the function for get the path of my file mp3, but when I run librosa.load I have this error

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Import libraries

```
import librosa
import librosa.display
```

Defined function

```
def get_audio_path(audio_dir, track_id):
    tid_str = '{:06d}'.format(track_id)
    return os.path.join(audio_dir, tid_str[:3], tid_str + '.mp3')
```

Plot single spectogram

```
filename = get_audio_path(AUDIO_DIR, 36096)
y, sr = librosa.load(filename)
print(len(y),sr)

RuntimeError: Error opening '/home/ub10/Project 1/fma_small/036/036096.mp3': File contains data in an unknown format.
```

> Please any solution for this issue or a different method !

Answer (score 0):

Use newest version of librosa. This should fix problem.

Comment: please what is the new version ?

Comment: Just use pip to upgrade it. sudo pip install [package_name] --upgrade

Comment: sudo apt-get install python3-pip